# JQuery: do I need to rewrite a script for window resize function?

Tags: jquery

```
    $(window).on( 'load' , function() {
        var secondspotlightTop = ( ( $( "#under-splash" ).height() - $( "#second-spotlight" ).height() ) * .5 );
        $( "#second-spotlight" ).css( "margin-top" , secondspotlightTop );
        $(window).resize( function() {
            var secondspotlightTop = ( ( $( "#under-splash" ).height() - $( "#second-spotlight" ).height() ) * .5 );
            $( "#second-spotlight" ).css( "margin-top" , secondspotlightTop );
        } );
    } );
```

Is there a way to name this function and call to it for the window resize function without having to copy and paste it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code to one function and call inside to window resize function

No need to repeat the code for normal and resize functions

```js
 $(window).on( 'load' , function() {
   function contsize()
      {
                var secondspotlightTop = ( ( $( "#under-splash" ).height() - $( "#second-spotlight" ).height() ) * .5 );
        $( "#second-spotlight" ).css( "margin-top" , secondspotlightTop );
      }
       contsize();
       $(window).bind("resize",function(){contsize();});
    } );
```